# fiddler sending same request every second

Tags: fiddler

I want to send a request with fiddler and want to send it **every second** same request.Is there any way to make this with fiddler.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html) for these kind of tests, but to answer your question, here is sample script which I got from [here](http://www.bayden.com/fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp)

```
public static ToolsAction("Crawl Sequential URLs") 
    function doCrawl(){ 
  var sBase: String;
  var sInt: String;

  sBase = FiddlerObject.prompt("Enter base URL with ## in place of the start integer", "http://www.example.com/img##.jpg");
  sInt = FiddlerObject.prompt("Start At", "1");
  var iFirst = int.Parse(sInt);
  sInt = FiddlerObject.prompt("End At", "12");
  var iLast = int.Parse(sInt);

  for (var x=iFirst; x<=iLast; x++)
  {
    //Replace 's' with your HTTP Request. Note: \ is a special character in JScript
    // If you want to represent a backslash in a string constant, double it like \\ 
    var s = "GET " + sBase.Replace("##", x.ToString()) + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"; 
    var b=false;
    while(!b){
    try{
      FiddlerObject.utilIssueRequest(s);
      b=true;
    }
    catch(e){
      var iT = Environment.TickCount + 10000;
      FiddlerObject.StatusText = "Waiting 10 sec because we have too many requests outstanding...";
      while (iT > Environment.TickCount){ Application.DoEvents(); }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to send this request https://www.kayahh.com/getstat.php?live_sess_get=1&_=1387652191344  where do i need to paste this in your code i m not expert in this :(

Comment: Click Rules > Customize Rules. Paste the ToolsAction block inside the Handlers{} class, right next to any of the other ones that are already there.

Comment: Hi, i would to ask how to handle special characters like "//"

Answer (score 3):

I would use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) with a batch file to do just that

From Fiddler, select one or more requests you want to repeat and head over to *File > Export Sessions > Selected Sessions*

[image]

Now select Curl Export and save the output as a .bat file
[image]

Now edit the batch file to make it run every 60 seconds

```
:loop
<your curl commands exported from Fiddler>
timeout /t 60
goto loop
```

Now save the batch file and run it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it, as you can write scripts in fiddler.

Anyway, I recommend you to use BURP for this purpose - you have built-in option to do it easily (repeater, for example).

See http://portswigger.net/burp/
and http://portswigger.net/burp/repeater.html (for repeater).

Comment: I want to add timer to my request with fiddlerscript. like this onbeforerequest event need to add here a timer or a delay and make it a loop to send a request every 1 second     if (oSession.url=="www.example.com/live.js") {
  oSession.url = "dev.example.com/workinprogress.js";
}